# Pyplot error when calling the axis function:

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am just trying to set the axis limits with pyplot, but it seems like it is not detecting the argument of the axis function correctly, as it returns this error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.
```

It is related to the axis function, but I can not see where the problem is. The part of my code which is giving the problem is the following:

```
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x[:,0],x[:,1])
    ax=[0.0,10.0,0.0,10.0]
    plt.axis(ax)
```

Comment: What is `x`? It would help us reproduce what you're doing.

Comment: Post the *entire* traceback and all of the relevant code.

Comment: I just copied the code EMS posted for testing, and I still get the same error, while it worked for him. Could there be some problem with my pyplot installation?

Comment: OK, never mind... for some reason, restarting the python interpreter solved the problem. That was unexpected. Thanks for the help, anyway

Answer (score 0):

If I use `x = numpy.random.randn(10,2)` then the remainder of this code works with no issue, using NumPy 1.4, matplotlib 1.1.1, and Python 2.7.3. The `axis` function in the `pyplot` API accepts a `list` of 4 values as the first positional argument, so the usage here is correct. The error you are experiencing does not come from this piece of code.

If you provide the full details of the data you are trying to plot and the full details of the code and traceback message, perhaps we can help you.

```
# Works fine assuming packages are installed...
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.randn(10,2)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1])
ax = [0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0]
plt.axis(ax)
plt.show()
```

Given the error message you've posted, one possibility is that you have taken the instance of a `list` object (the thing called `ax` in your code) that was intended to serve as the boundary of an axis and confused it with the API function `axis`. In that case, look in your code for a place where you put the function call syntax after the variable name of `ax`, such as:

```
ax(x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

instead of

```
plt.axis(x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

In the first case, trying to "call" `ax` with some arguments will not succeed, since the Python `list` class does not implement the `__call__` protocol, so that suffixing the function call symbols, `()` (potentially with arguments) after the variable name of a variable that is an instance of `list` will cause the error you are seeing.

Other things may cause it too, but this is my best guess given the limited info available in the question.

Comment: OK, I think there might be something wrong with my pyplot library. I just copied and pasted the code with the random x you posted and I get the very same error. I am using the distribution included in winpython with python 2.7.